# How to escape '(' in Karate feature file

Tags: karate

I am trying to do an assertion in my feature file where my expected value is having '('

Is there any escape character to be used in the feature file. I have used '\' as escape character but no luck

Karate feature file statement:

```
And match response ProcessCustomer/header/status/description == 'Successful(EFT Payment)'
```

Getting below error:

```
com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: ESB_PaymentCardPayment.feature:20 - syntax error, expected '==' for match
```

The same statement works if I use 'contains' instead of '=='

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be missing something, maybe unpack the XML value first into a string and try again. There is no special behavior for strings, try the following two lines and see it work:

```
* def test = 'Successful(EFT Payment)'
* match test == 'Successful(EFT Payment)'
* def xml = <root>Successful(EFT Payment)</root>
* match xml/root == 'Successful(EFT Payment)'
```